# Code obfuscation do not understand

Tags: c

I encountered the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long long P = 1,E = 2,T = 5,A = 61,L = 251,N = 3659,R = 271173410,G = 1479296389,
              x[] = { G * R * E * E * T , P * L * A * N * E * T };
    puts((char*)x);
    return 0;
}
```

The case is I do not quite understand how it works,It is very confusing to me. Can someone you please explain this in detail?

**edit:** One more thing, how to print "Hola mundo!" ("Hello world" in Spanish) analogically?

Comment: Calculate `G * R * E * E * T` and `P * L * A * N * E * T` and see how their byte sequence looks like.

Comment: @GSerg I do not understand

Comment: @Tony ,  _how to make print hello world in Spanish_   `printf("hola mundo");`

Comment: @Tony: `x` is equal to {`0x6f57206f6c6c6548`,`0x21646c72`}, which gives you "Hello World!" when you convert it to ASCII.

Comment: @Qiu post it as an answer and perhaps split the sequence byte per byte to prove it.

Comment: @Arun A.S I mean how to get the equivalent in Spanish with the method I expressed

Comment: @Tony Convert the Spanish text to hex (ASCII) and come up with numbers that, when multiplied, will result in that hex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oh, this one is fun.
Obviously you declare many `long long` variables, and one `long long` array of 2 cells. The array is therefore made of 16 bytes.

Given that each byte is one `ASCII` character, the array represents 16 characters (while the last one is probably zero). You can see that:

```
G * R * E * E * T = 1479296389 * 271173410 * 2 *2 * 5 = 8022916924116329800 = 
0x6F57206F6C6C6548

P * L * A * N * E * T = 1 * 251 * 61 * 3659 * 2 * 5 = 560229490 = 
0x21646C72
```

Given that your processor is [Little Endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian), the array's in-memory representation is:

```
48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 57 6F 72 6C 64 21 00 00 00 00
```

Which is `Hello World!\x00\x00\x00\x00` in ASCII.

Comment: @Mark Segal excellent answer, only a matter more as printing on Spanish

Comment: @Tony - the output of this program is 'Hello World!' - exactly as typed. https://ideone.com/d2RLuR

Comment: If you want it to be printed in Spanish, it depends if Spanish is all basic ASCII (or maybe a non-standard encoding is required, or even Unicode or something). If it's ASCII compatible, you should simply see how 'Hello World' is represented in Spanish and how you can play with the code so it will do so.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Spanish variant:

```
int main(void)
{
    int T=1, E=2, R=2, A=31, Q=784, L=70684, I=6590711, U=1181881,
        x[] = { T*I*E*R*R*A, Q*U*E, T*A*L };

    puts((char *) x);

    return 0;
}
```